# How to get the best feature or gens from "random_search(n,dim)" using python code?

Tags: python-3.x, regression, binary-search, feature-selection, cuckoo

I have get the feature or gens from random_search(n,dim), but if i re-run the program, the result always change or different from the result befor. 
I want the feature selection (gens) have the same result, although i want to re-run the program/code.

I cant get the same result if i re-run the code or program

' python

## Code BCS for feature selection

```
def BCS(Eval_Func,m_i=200,n=24,minf=0,dim=None,prog=False,alpha=0.1,beta=1.5,param=0.25):

    estimate=Eval_Func().evaluate

    if dim==None:
        dim=Eval_Func().check_dimentions(dim)
    pa=param
    #flag=dr
    gens=random_search(n,dim)
    fit=[float("-inf") if minf == 0 else float("inf") for _ in range(n)]
    pos=[0 for _ in range(n)]
    g_pos=[0]*dim
    g_val=float("-inf") if minf == 0 else float("inf")
    gens_dict={tuple([0]*dim):float("-inf") if minf == 0 else float("inf")}
    if prog:
        miter=tqdm(range(m_i))
    else:
        miter=range(m_i)
    for it in miter:
        for i,g in enumerate(gens):
            if tuple(g) in gens_dict:
                score=gens_dict[tuple(g)]
            else:
                score=estimate(g)
                gens_dict[tuple(g)]=score
            if score > fit[i] if minf==0 else score < fit[i]:
                fit[i]=score
                pos[i]=g

        maxfit,maxind=max(fit),fit.index(max(fit))
        minfit,minind=min(fit),fit.index(min(fit))
        if minf==0:
            if maxfit > g_val:
                g_val=dc(maxfit)
                g_pos=dc(gens[maxind])
        else:
            if minfit < g_val:
                g_val=dc(minfit)
                g_pos=dc(gens[minind])

        if pa < random.uniform(0,1):
            if minf==0:
                gens[minind]=[0 if 0.5>random.uniform(0,1) else 1 for _ in  range(dim)]#rand_gen()
                fit[minind]=float("-inf") if minf == 0 else float("inf")
            else:
                gens[maxind]=[0 if 0.5>random.uniform(0,1) else 1 for _ in range(dim)]#rand_gen()
                fit[maxind]=float("-inf") if minf == 0 else float("inf")


        for g in gens:
            for d in range(dim):
                x=levy_flight(beta,g_pos[d],g[d],alpha)
                if random.uniform(0,1) < sigmoid(x):
                    g[d]=1
                else:
                    g[d]=0
    return g_val,g_pos,g_pos.count(1)
```

## Code form Class Evaluate

```
class Evaluate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.train_l = tr_y
        self.train_d = tr_x
        self.test_l = te_y
        self.test_d=te_x
        self.K = 2
    def evaluate(self,gen):
        mask=np.array(gen) > 0
        al_data=np.array([al[mask] for al in self.train_d])
        #al_test_data=np.array([al[mask] for al in self.test_d])
        kf = ms.KFold(n_splits=self.K,random_state=42)
        s = 0
        for tr_ix,te_ix in kf.split(al_data):
            s+= svm.SVR(kernel = 'rbf', gamma='scale', C=1.0,  epsilon=0.2).fit(al_data[tr_ix],self.train_l[tr_ix]).score(al_data[te_ix],self.train_l[te_ix])#.predict(al_test_data)
        s/=self.K
        return s#np.count_nonzero(self.test_l==res)/len(self.test_l)

    def check_dimentions(self,dim):
        if dim==None:
            return len(self.train_d[0])
        else:
            return dim
```

## Code For Test_score

```
def test_score(gen,tr_x,tr_y,te_x,te_y):
    mask=np.array(gen) == 1
    al_data=np.array(tr_x[:,mask])
    al_test_data=np.array(te_x[:,mask])
    return np.mean(np.abs(([svm.SVR(kernel = 'rbf', gamma='scale', C=1.0, epsilon=0.2).fit(al_data,tr_y).score(al_test_data,te_y) for i in range(4)])))*100
```

## Code for call the Program BCS and Class Evaluate

```
def fitureSelection(data):
    result = []
    for i in range(0,2):
        X = data.loc[data['label']== i].iloc[:,0:93]
        y = data.loc[data['label']== i].iloc[:,95]
        tr_x, te_x, tr_y, te_y = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)
        sc_X = StandardScaler()
        tr_x = sc_X.fit_transform(tr_x)
        te_x = sc_X.fit_transform(te_x)
        s,g,l = BCS(Eval_Func=Evaluate,n=20,m_i=200)
        result.append("".join(map(str,g)))
    return result
```

## Code for call the def fitureSelection(data)

```
hasil = fitureSelection(Hasilcolend)
```

## The result

```
['000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
```

'000000000000100000010000000000000000000100000000000000001100000000000000000001010001000000000']
'

Comment: I suggest editing the question to have one single code region, at present several individual copy-and-paste actions must be taken to try and run your code. Anyone trying to help would have to guess at the import statements you made, so please also include those to make running the code easier. People here should be able to easily copy the code you post into a single file and run it.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion